# How to programmatically add default values to existing nodes of a specific content type

Tags: nodes

On a Drupal 7 site, I have a content type that is populated with existing nodes. Later, I added a new boolean field (that is required). The existing nodes now have a blank value for this field.

How do I programmatically populate these nodes with a default value?

Comment: "programmatically".. do you like SQL, "raw" PHP or snippets of PHP + contrib modules better?

Comment: I'm fairly new to drupal, so SQL or PHP + contrib modules might be better than "raw" PHP.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I g2g now. I might be able to give you something workable tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use module [Views Bulk Operation](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). Then create views page like table and field title, your field, add field **Content: Bulk operations (Bulk operations)** with settings VIEWS BULK OPERATIONS -> SELECTED OPERATIONS **Execute arbitrary PHP script (views_bulk_operations_script_action)**. Save, Open the page, select one node, choose **Execute arbitrary PHP script**

enter next code and execute:

```
//change entity title or what you want to do
$entity -> title = $entity->title . ' test';

//save entity
entity_save('node', $entity);
```

Comment: in your case $entity -> title = $entity->title . ' test'; must be like this $entity -> field_my_boolean['und'][0]['value'] = 1; for exampple

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone runs into this in the future: install [Field Defaults](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_defaults).

> Field Defaults allows batch updating of default field values to
>   existing content. When adding a new field to an entity you can update
>   all existing content with the default value or when editing an
>   existing field you can choose to also update all existing content with
>   the new value.